# jOOQ: Database-agnostic way of disabling constraints

Tags: constraints, jooq, database-agnostic

I'd like to know if there's a way to disable database constraints in jOOQ for different databases in an agnostic way. For example, disabling foreign key constraints in MySQL and PostgreSQL differs quite a lot:

**MySQL**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

**PostgreSQL**

Not actually too sure, but will probably involve disabling triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of feature is extremely vendor specific - it would be hard to standardise on a feature like this. In jOOQ's DDL interpreter, however, this is supported starting from jOOQ 3.13: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8105

But since you're only looking for support in two databases, you could roll your own:

```java
void disableForeignKeys(Configuration configuration) {
    switch (configuration.family()) {
        case MYSQL:
            DSL.using(configuration).execute("set foreign_key_checks=0");
            break;
        case POSTGRES:
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, I thought as much. Thanks for the clarifying.